# Need some help combining 2 jQuery scripts and behaviors

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, character-encoding

Ι need to use a combination of the following 2 scripts but despite all the combinations I've done so far, I fail to get it to work 100%.

I use a colorbox to display products detail pages in which there is a form with various fields for adding the items to the cart. Upon submitting the form, I want to show an alert and then close the colorbox so that the underlying page (that opened the colorbox in the forst place) stays as is.

With this script

```
$("#productadd").submit(function(){ // WORKS FINE EXCEPT THE ENCODING
  $.post(
    $(this).attr('action'),
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
      alert('Product was added to your order');  
    $().colorbox.close();
});
```

everything works fine except for the encoding which in my case is iso-8859-7 (greek).
If I use this script then encoding is ok but the post is being made with the default behaviour, redirection to the url defined in the form's action.

```
      $("#productadd").submit(function(){ //ENCODING OK, COLORBOX.CLOSE() AND ALERT FAIL
         $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "text/html; charset=iso-8859-7");
            },
            success: function(json) {
                alert('Product added to cart!'),  
                $().colorbox.close(),
                itemAddCallback(json);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#error").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

If there's a jQuery equivalent for xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "text/html; charset=iso-8859-7") I'd be more than happy to use it. Also, what do I declare as data: so I dont get a 'data is not defined' error? (despite the error, date submits fine).

**UPDATE**: After various suggestions from those who answered so far, this is what my code looks like:

```
      $("#productadd").submit(function(){ 
         $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'text',
            mimeType: "text/html; iso-8859-7", 
            success: function() {
                alert('Item added to your order'),  
                $().colorbox.close();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#error").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

My only problem is that although it submits and displays the alert etc, the submitted data is encoded in utf-8 instead of iso-8859-7, any ideas?

Comment: It's probably better later, then never... Anyway, please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15205281/655756) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Find **mimeType** property.

```
mimeType(added 1.5.1)String

A mime type to override the XHR mime type.
```

Therefore you need to add following:

```
$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    mimeType: "text/html; charset=iso-8859-7"...
```

Comment: Thank you, nice tip. However, my main problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

In the shorthand POST request you send `$(this).serialize()` as data, so I suppose you want to send the same form data in the other request.

To debug the requests, use your browsers net panel and find out if the requests actually fire and what the responses are (F12 then Net > XHR).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont see any requests except for the post. Is my code correct, should I place the call to alert in a different function?

Comment: Have you set the data parameter to $(this).serialize()?
And what is the statuscode of the response?

Comment: Ok, i got it right now, status code 200 etc and I see the post values correctly in the developer tools but in my pages they appear as utf-8.
So, to narrow this down, I'm after the right mimetype and/or datatype in ajax but I cant nail it.